# cluster activation failing due to cman service

Tags: debian, cluster, mount, gfs2

I have a 50TB SAN device, which inturn has two partitions. One of the partition is a gfs2 configured to be shared between two nodes. However, I'm having trouble mounting this partition on one node, but not on the other one.

When I try to mount it I get the follwing error,

```
gfs_controld join connect error: error mounting lockproto lock_dlm
```

I figure it has something to do with cman as it says that it failed to get dbus connection right, but this service looks fine in the other node. Below is the output from cman service on the problematic node.

```
# systemctl status cman.service
# cman.service - LSB: Starts and stops cman
#  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cman)
#  Active: active (running) since mån 2016-08-01 15:44:37 CEST; 1h 48min ago
#  CGroup: /system.slice/cman.service
#          ├─1512 corosync -f
#          ├─1563 fenced
#          └─1579 dlm_controld

aug 01 15:44:34 cluster1 cman[1351]: Waiting for quorum... [  OK  ]
aug 01 15:44:34 cluster1 cman[1351]: Starting fenced... [  OK  ]
aug 01 15:44:34 cluster1 fenced[1563]: fenced 3.1.8 started
aug 01 15:44:34 cluster1 fenced[1563]: failed to get dbus connection
aug 01 15:44:34 cluster1 dlm_controld[1579]: dlm_controld 3.1.8 started
aug 01 15:44:35 cluster1 cman[1351]: Starting dlm_controld... [  OK  ]
aug 01 15:44:35 cluster1 fence_node[1637]: unfence cluster1 success
aug 01 15:44:35 cluster1 cman[1351]: Unfencing self... [  OK  ]
aug 01 15:44:37 cluster1 cman[1351]: Joining fence domain... [  OK  ]
aug 01 15:44:37 miles systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts and stops cman.
```

Here is the LSB header section from cman service file for your reference,(The LSB comment headers of cman had corosync $remote-fs as Required-Start/Required-Stop. Since *_gfs2.mount are in remote-fs.target and needs to be started after cman and corosync, this is impossible to satisfy. Therfore, I've removed $remote_fs in /etc/init.d/cman and /etc/init.d/corosync)

```
!/bin/bash

 cman - Cluster Manager init script

 chkconfig: - 21 79
 description: Starts and stops cman


BEGIN INIT INFO
Provides:             cman
Required-Start:       $network $time 
Required-Stop:        $network $time 
Default-Start:        S
Default-Stop:         0 6
Short-Description:    Starts and stops cman
Description:          Starts and stops the Cluster Manager set of daemons
END INIT INFO
```

I'm not sure what is causing this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

For your reference, I'm using

gfs2-cluster v 3.1.3-1.2

kernel v3.16.0-4-amd64

Debian 8

I'm new to these waters so kindly bear with me if I've missed something and please let me know if you need more information from my side.

Thank you very much!

Cheers,

R